# Pure CSS Responsive Multilevel Menu

Tags: css

I'm trying to modify [This project of Osvaldas Valutis](http://codepen.io/massiebn/pen/KrJvi) adding a 3rd and 4th level, but my css knowledge is not so deep and the result, as you can see [HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqLWOG) is very poor:

besides HTML, on CSS side I added

```
* third level */

#nav li li li{
    background-color: #cc470d;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
#nav li li:hover li {
    display: block;
    left: 2px;
    top:0px;
    right: 0;
}
#nav li:not( :first-child ):hover ul li ul li {
    left: 240px;
    top:-50px;
}
#nav li ul li ul a {
    font-size: 1.25em; /* 20 */
    border-top: 1px solid #e15a1f;
    padding: 0.75em; /* 15 (20) */
}

#nav li ul li ul li a:hover, #nav li ul li ul:not( :hover ) li.active a {
    background-color: #e15a1f;
}
```

but clearly it is not enough, and then I have to handle also the @media versions.

can please suggest what need to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply fixed widths to the dropdowns, then adjust the margins to position them correctly.

Change your code for the third level `#nav li li li` to this:

```
/* third level */

#nav li li li {
    background-color: #cc470d;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 240px; /* will also set width for child dropdown */
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

And add this for the fourth level:

```
/* fourth level */

#nav li li li li {
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, I implemented your suggestion and some other changes and situation has improved, [SEE HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqLWOG)  but still not perfect.
Particularly, when opens Third level remains a big orange square on bottom of second level that I do not know how to avoid. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just add `#nav li li ul {  height: 0; }` to your CSS.

Comment: that's great!, I added some minor changes and rules to apply your last suggestion only to min-width 1000px and that's it.
for anybody could be interested here [my final version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqLWOG).